# Linking dependencies on OSX

Tags: ros, linking, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have been attempting to get ROS to work on OSX and am stuck when I try to link an executable with a dependency. I tried linking against yaml-cpp and tinyxml, both installed and linked according to homebrew, but I get the following message:

```
ld: library not found for -lyaml-cpp
```

Executing :

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs yaml-cpp
```

Gives me :

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/yaml-cpp/0.5.0/include  -L/usr/local/Cellar/yaml-cpp/0.5.0/lib -lyaml-cpp
```

Doesn't that mean rosmake should be able to find it? For the record, I am linking in my CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
target_link_libraries(Controller yaml-cpp)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54041/linking-dependencies-on-osx/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are adding yaml-cpp as a target, but the -L location of it is not on your path:

/usr/local/Cellar/yaml-cpp/0.5.0/lib

This means you need to use `find_package` or `pkg-config` in CMake to find this path at build time and add it your linker path using `link_directories()`

Also, you might want to use yaml-cpp version 0.3, because that is what ROS is using. See:

https://github.com/ros/homebrew-groovy/blob/master/yaml-cpp-0.3.rb

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-03**:
Thank you again. It seems I had both versions of yaml-cpp installed. I have some follow-up questions, would I need to do this on say Ubuntu as well? Did this change since groovy? I remember on fuerte that I could just link it like I showed. Can you give me an example of how I should link in?

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-04**:
I tried making a small test package on Ubuntu and what I did does indeed work (add target_link_libraries and add rosdep to manifest). On the Ubuntu machine the lib was .so however and on my OSX it is a .a, does this make a difference? Why doesn't my ROS automatically use the path from pkg-config?

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-04**:
My guess is that I have some environment setting that is messed up, causing the compiler to fail to see the libraries. What could it be?

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-04**:
It depends on what you are doing, are you using rosbuild or catkin. Either way you need to find yaml-cpp in cmake before using it, it probably works on Ubuntu because it is installed in your library path, but you should not rely on this being the case on all systems, i.e. Homebrew and osx.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-04**:
Check this out for a hint out how to do this with CMake: http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=127

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-04**:
I see, that clears it up for me a lot. Too bad you can't rely on that :)

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-04**:
Ok I believe I have that part down now, however I get a different error now:

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-04**:
Edit your original question if it is related to this still, otherwise open a new issue.

**Comment by [Jean-Luc Nacif Coelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/20055/jean-luc-nacif-coelho/) on 2014-08-20**:
How do you add it to the linker path? I am having the same problem.